# Creating LSD-SLAM static library for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, static-libraries, augmented-reality

I'm trying to create a LSD-SLAM static library in order to use it on an iOS app. 
Does someone know a good tutorial or maybe if someone converted the library to iOS already?

Thanks

The library is the following: https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam

Comment: excellent, http://vision.in.tum.de/research/lsdslam

Comment: did you ever find a solution?